# Breaking a git merge into easier to handle chunks

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch to merge into another git branch, however some of the files have varied wildly.

When running the merge tool I have been resolving the conflicts; however for some conflicts it becomes massively complex and is more like trial and error so I have had to abort a few times and start again from a clean working state. This means I'm reproducing a lot of work, when I know the correct conflict resolution has been made.

What I would like to do is break the merge down into smaller parts, so I can commit it piecemeal. Is there a way to break a merge into smaller pieces? I can only seem to merge to the head of the second branch.

Comment: Just pass a SHA to git merge instead of the branch name ?

Comment: Just break up the branch you're trying to merge into smaller chunks?

Comment: Thanks Andrew C! - I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223103/merge-up-to-a-specific-commit