# How to merge up to specific commit id from a remote branch in Git

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I am working in a forked repository, where all my development work is on the local repo, but then merged back into the fork. We have a long-term development branch, that I would like to sync up with `main` on occasion.

However, because of the complexity of my dependencies, I don't want to merge directly from the HEAD of main; I want to identify a specific commit, and only merge up to that point.

Two remotes:

- origin
- official

I have looked at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223103/merge-up-to-a-specific-commit), but it does not seem to address my specific situation.

I am working in origin, but the branch I am merging from is in official. The commit in the history that I hope to merge from is 0c084b4408 (on the official remote repo).

```
git merge --no-commit official/0c084b4408
```

When I do this, I get the message `merge: official/0c084b4408 - not something we can merge`

Easy enough to simply merge from the HEAD of a given branch in the official repo, but merging to a specific commit doesn't seem to be an option.

Is there a way to do this?

Do I need to specify a branch also? I wouldn't have thought so, since a commit is a commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `git merge 0c084b4408`, the id is the commit's true name, its real identity. [refnames and other revision expressions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) are resolved to ids *very* early, that's what the command's trying to do with the string you gave it.

Comment: Well, huh. I didn't think commit ID's would cross the boundary between forks. TIL.

Thanks!!