Merge only branch-specific changes
In our git workflow we have two merge destinations: a dev branch which holds all the work from our finished feature branches, and a release branch where we left out some features that are not yet ready for practical use and apply some extra settings. These two branches diverged sometime in the past.
Our feature branches are based on dev. If the feature needs to be in release we need to merge it there, too -- and that's a problem: Git will put lots of the dev specific commits into release while we want it to only merge the changes from the feature branch.
Currently we manage this with a lot of cherry-picks which isn't very practical. I'm aware that there is a simple way to merge up to a certain commit (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8223166/2733244) but is there something similar for a start commit? Or some rebase trick?

You can do a rebase of a given feature branch rather easily: git checkout --detach the-feature; git rebase dev @ --onto release. I am detaching so that the original branch does not move.

Like @eftshift0 said there could be a solution if you are willing to make dev a descendant of release or somehow make it so that you can merge between the two. But if you (see the title) want to “merge only branch-specific changes”? git-merge(1) isn’t designed for that kind of selective inclusion. And what people again and again fall into is indeed maintaining two divergent histories manually. Which is what makes such a workflow a dead-end with regards to long-term productivity.
